# why outline css property not working in react-native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, outline

I can not see outline border and colour in native version of the application , meanwhile it works okay with web application,

```
            backgroundColor: '#065B61',
            marginRight: -20,
            shadowColor: "black",
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
            shadowOpacity: 1,
            shadowRadius: 4.00,
            elevation: 24,
            marginBottom: 15,
            outlineWidth: 10,
            outlineStyle: "auto",
            outlineColor: 'white',
        }
    }
```

Comment: On what element type your applying this? View, TextInput, Font?

Comment: I am applying these on a View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all css properties are supported in React Native. They might work on web but non on native devices. List of supported [View style props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props). You can see there are no `outline` props. The solution is to use `border` props, `borderWidth`, `borderStyle` & `borderColor` -

```
borderColor: 'black',
borderStyle: 'solid',
borderWidth: 3
```